# Static UITableView or UICollectionView in custom XIB?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiview, uiscrollview

You can define static cells in UITableViews with Storyboard if you use UITableViewControllers. However, it doesn't seem possible with UITableViews or even UICollectionViews.

The goal is to define a slide out menu that is overlaid on an existing UIView. The existing UIView should not move as is the case with most implementations.

Options (neither seem ideal):

- Use UITableView but define all the menu options programmatically instead of using Storyboard.
- Mimic UITableView functionality with a UIScrollView.

Is there a better option? If not, any gotchas with using a UIScrollView?

Answer (score 0):

In the table view controller just select the table view then from the settings pane select static cell as in this image :
[image]

then select the section-1 in the sub tree of the table view and choose the number of rows you want :

[image]

then select the row cells you want to customise and you can have your static uitableView

Hope this helps you

Comment: add a uitable view in the container view in the xib file and follow the same steps and it will work

Comment: as mentioned in the question, there is no option for static cells when using a uitableview. you have to use a uitableviewcontroller to see that option.

Answer (score 0):

Static table view cells are only available when using storyboards. However, if you aren't using storyboards for your entire UI you can still use them for individual screens instead of a collection of screens.

To do this you can create a UIStoryboard file with a single view controller on it that has it's File's Owner set to your custom view controller subclass. Set the VC's identifier to some value. When you want to display this, get the storyboard and then instantiate your view controller subclass by creating the VC from your storyboard.

```
  UIStoryboard *tableViewStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"your storyboard" bundle:nil];
  CustomViewController = [tableViewStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"custom identifier"];
```

You can present this VC as usual in your app.

This is a great way to start using storyboards without having to convert your entire app to use them.